# Google Sheet conditional formatting, highlight just 1 cell in a range based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How can I highlight a cell in a range, if its value is equal to a different cell?

Example:
Random numbers in range A5:A20.
I want to highlight a cell in this range if it is equal to B4.

```
     [  A  ][  B  ][  C  ]  
[ 3 ]
[ 4 ]         24  
[ 5 ]  20  
[ 6 ]  24
[ 7 ]  18
```

In this case I would want only cell A6 to highlight as it equals B4.

I feel like it should be easy, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "format cells if equal to...", but there are a couple of things to watch for:

- the reference to B4 should be B$4, with an absolute row number
- the rule "if equal to... B$4" would mean the cell value has to be literally "B$4". You want "if equal to... =B$4"

[image: formatting]